# .htaccess in subdirectory doesn't work?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need help with two .htaccess files - one in root of the webserver and second in subfolder.

.htaccess in root directory is working fine

/var/www

```
Options +FollowSymLinks MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

.htaccess in subdirectory - doesnt work

/var/www/subdirectory

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A1
Header append Cache-Control must-revalidate
```

Apache config - I have two virtualhosts - one for 80 and second for 443.
In *80 I have directory options

```
     <Directory /var/www/>
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
     </Directory>
```

In the subfolder I have .html files and this htaccess should treat them as php. Am I missing something ?

Just a note - whole PHP code is commented in html when I use inspect element.
PHP 5.6 Apache 2.4.0

Comment: Have you confirmed that `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html` is the correct directive for your server? And the `Cache-Control` is not being set? Do you need `MultiViews`?

Comment: Hi, yes AddType application/x-httpd-php .html this is correct. Anyway I resolved my problem, see answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I managed to resolve my problem,

missing expire modul

```
a2enmod expire
```

Missing the same directive directory in 443 virtualhost

I commented this line Header append Cache-Control must-revalidate